# How to use central handler for all Input validation in all Views

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, validation, mvp

In a MVP `Winforms` application I'm doing initial validations in the `View` using following method. (Though business logic related validation done in the `Model`). In `Form's` constructor using a `foreach` loop I'm delegating all `TextBoxe's` `Validating` event to this handler.

```
//Validates all text boxes in the form
private void textBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox currenttb = (TextBox)sender;
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(currenttb.Text))
        {
            currenttb.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed;
            currenttb.Name.Substring(3)));
        }

        else
        {
            e.Cancel = false;
            currenttb.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
}


public Form()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //In form's constructor, following eventhanderlrs are hooked up to validating events of controllers,
    //there for one controller type shares a single handler

    foreach (TextBox tb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(x => x.CausesValidation))
    {
        tb.Validating += textBox_Validating;
    }
 }
```

Without repeating this code in every `View`. it'd better if I could keep it in a one place. So could you show me a better way to keep this centrally making it available to all `Views`?

**NOTE:** My View is not aware of the `Model` and `Presenter`. `Presenter`'s `ShowView()` method is invoked to display the `View` to user. I cant do this validation in `Presenter` as the presenter access the `View` through `IView's` public properties so the validation should take place even before the Presenter act on those properties.

**EDIT:**

For ex. IView has properties like

```
void int ID {get; set;}
void string Name {get; set;}
```

etc.

If the presenter is supposed to do the validate like

```
private void ValidateID()
{
    try
    {
        Validate (_View.ID);
    }
    catch {}
}
```

So what would happened if the user had kept the `txtID.text` empty? This would lead to an exception in the view when it tries to convert null value to int.

Please note that this explanation is totally based on my understanding of the matter and kindly let me know if I've missed anything .

Comment: Shouldn't this validation be done when the form is submitted not when it is created?

Comment: @Adrian Hristov, This step is only for primary validation and user notification. On save/submit also, entire form will be validated in a similar way but without letting user to ignore.

Comment: What is the purpose of the validation? Can you explain more detailed why you cannot do the validation in the presenter. The best place to put validation is in the presenter so you should work towards resolving the issue with presenter not being an option

Comment: @Adrian Hristov, If you don't mind please see the EDIT:

Comment: I remember on one of your other questions you were asking basically the same thing. So you should really review your code and remove as much logic as you can from the **View** other than firing events and simple UI configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of keeping an `int` property in the **View** interface you can keep a `string`. This way when you get the user's input there would be no way of throwing an exception because there would be no parsing in the code-behind. You would then make the parsing in the **Presenter**. By doing so you can have a centralized place to validate the input.

The **View**'s job is to only supply the user's input to the **Presenter** not to validate it.

By following my suggestions if you have to do the same validation on a lot of places you can make a base **Presenter** class that other **Presenters** are inheriting from and put the validation there. It would certainly be easier than making a base `Form` that other forms are inheriting from.